# Размещение ImageView по центру макета по горизонтали

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Имеется xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProgramActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <!--android:scaleType="centerInside"/>-->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу разместить ImageView по центру. Для этого использовал

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <!--android:scaleType="centerInside"/>-->
```

Но все равно не помогло. Пробовал даже в `gravity` поставить `center`, но изображение все равно не центрируется. В чем проблема? И еще вопрос, как автоматически подогнать изображение пропорционально под ширину экрана. Пытался в `width` поставить `match_parent`, а в `height` `wrap_content`, но не помогло, хотя кажется немного логичным

Comment: android:layout_centerHorizontal - выравнивание по центру родителя по горизонтали
android:layout_centerVertical - выравнивание по центру родителя по вертикали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `RelativeLayout` нужно использовать:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"    //выравнивание по горизонтали
android:layout_centerVertical="true"      //выравнивание по вертикали
android:layout_centerInParent="true"      //выравнивание по вертикали и горизонтали
```